# Javascript Slideshow How to make it DRYer

Tags: javascript, events, slideshow

I've created a simple automatic/manual slideshow in Javascript, but I need help with making it DRYer.

Here is my Javascript code:

```
let image = document.getElementById('slideImg');
const button = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
const imageArray = ['Images/baby.jpg', 'Images/botez-leagan.jpg', 'Images/tata.jpg'];

let i = 0;
let time = 5000;

loadEventHandlers();
window.onload= autoSlide;


function loadEventHandlers(){
  button[0].addEventListener('click', changeImg);
  button[1].addEventListener('click', changeImg);
}


function autoSlide(){

  image.classList.add('animate');

  image.src = imageArray[i];
  if(i < imageArray.length - 1){
    i++;
    }else{
    i = 0;
    }
  console.log(image);

  setTimeout("autoSlide()", time);


  }


  function changeImg(){
    image.src = imageArray[i];
    image.classList.add('animate');

  if(i < imageArray.length - 1){
    i++;
    }else {
    i=0;
    }
```

And the relevant HTML

```
   <div class="gallery">

  <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="" class="slide" id="slideImg">
  </div>



  <a class="prev btn" >&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next btn" >&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

I initially thought of combining the timeout function with the click event, however, I couldn't figure out how to check for something like this: "If button has been clicked, change image" and "If button has not been clicked, wait X seconds and change image" as well as "If button has been clicked wait x seconds and if button has NOT been clicked, change image".

I'd also like to reset the animation each time an image changes, but I'm not sure if I can add a Timeout function within the autoSlide() function.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Thank you, 
Bogdan

Comment: Instead of `setTimeout`, try defining a single sliding function that will go either forwards or backwards based on some parameter. On page load, you can use `setInterval` to call that function with the forwards parameter every X amount of time, or on button click you can use `clearInterval` to cancel the timer and then manually trigger the sliding function with either the forwards or backwards parameter as necessary. (Don't have time to prepare an answer for you, sorry.)